# RoR: how can I list only microposts that have a certain attribute in one column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I am listing all of a users microposts using the code below.

```
<div class="span8">

            <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
            <h3>Purchases I am interested in (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
              <ol class="microposts">
                <%= render @microposts %>
              </ol>
              <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
```

and the view that renders for _micropost.html.erb is as follows

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

so this works fine, however I am changing things up. Every micropost has a hidden_tag_field which is a string (and a column in the database) that is called kind. It can be either "purchase" or "sale". I want to list all of the purchase microposts in one place and all the sale microposts in another. How can I change the micropost view to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
@purchases = @microposts.where(:kind => 'purchase')
@sales = @microposts.where(:kind => 'sale')
```

View:

```
<h2>Purchases</h2>
<%= render @purchases %>

<h2>Sales</h2>
<%= render @sales %>
```

Comment: that was a really good idea. I still get an error but I decided I needed to rewrite the question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469755/ror-nil-is-not-an-activemodel-compatible-object-that-returns-a-valid-partial)